# Django build efficiency with API

Tags: python, django

I have silly question about efficiency of django.
I will build application based on templates and using API.

Which option will be better?

1) 1 server, 1 django (template+djangorestframework in one running framework)

2) 1 server, 1 djangorestframework or flask api, 1 django template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the first solution is more simple and the efficience is similar.